# Помогите определить тип синтаксической конструкции

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис

Допускается ли постановка двоеточия между приложением и определяемым словом, если в предложении содержится особое предупреждение о последующем разъяснении? Я имею в виду случаи, когда сочетание приложения с определяемым словом является законченным по смыслу высказыванием и оформлено как самостоятельная синтаксическая  единица, например: "Ответ (какой?): он умер от горя". Или двоеточие здесь является не допустимым, а безальтернативным    знаком, для постановки которого имеется совершенно иное основание - бессоюзное сложное предложение, между частями которого складываются пояснительные отношения?

Заранее благодарю и надеюсь, что мое незнание лингвистической терминологии, да и теории языка вообще, не помешает вам понять суть вопроса.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем примере трудно увидеть приложение и определяемое слово. Думаю, что между частями предложения не определительная, а изъяснительная связь, и тогда приходится думать о том, как эту связь обозначить.

Наиболее приемлемым является вариант: "Ответ (таков): он умер от горя". Это БСП (значение изъяснения), первое предложение можно считать неполным (пропущено сказуемое).

Иногда можно использовать нестандартное оформление прямой речь, например: Пришло письмо с ответом "Он умер от горя". Это прямая речь в роли определения - вряд ли ее можно назвать приложением, хотя по значению есть сходство. Но классическим приложением мы считаем определение, выраженное существительным. Кроме того, существуют несогласованные определения.

Comment: Логично, спасибо.